# How to sum the scores from each round in my dice game?

Tags: python

I created this dice game. How can I sum the score from each round after the user says they do not want to roll again? Thank you!!!

```
import colorama
colorama.init()

print_in_green = "\x1b[32m"
print_in_red = "\x1b[31m"
print_in_blue = "\x1b[36m"
print_in_pink = "\x1b[35m"
print_default = "\x1b[0m"

import random
min = 1
max = 6
game_response = input("Would you like to roll your dice (y/n)? ")

if game_response == "y":
    roll_again = "yes"

    while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
        print("Rolling the dices...")
        print("The values are:")
        dice1 = random.randint(min, max)
        dice2 = random.randint(min, max)
        print(print_in_pink)
        print(int(dice1))
        print(int(dice2))
        print(print_default)
        score = (int(dice1) + int(dice2))
        roll_again = input("Your score for this round is " + str(score) + ". Roll the dices again (y/n)? ")
else:
    print("Ok!")
```

Comment: Create a variable that is used for counting, and increment it each time the user rolls. Finally print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the score up to sum. And print the sum after they decide not to roll any more.

```html
import colorama
colorama.init()

print_in_green = "\x1b[32m"
print_in_red = "\x1b[31m"
print_in_blue = "\x1b[36m"
print_in_pink = "\x1b[35m"
print_default = "\x1b[0m"

import random
min = 1
max = 6
sum = 0
game_response = input("Would you like to roll your dice (y/n)? ")

if game_response == "y":
    roll_again = "yes"

    while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
        print("Rolling the dices...")
        print("The values are:")
        dice1 = random.randint(min, max)
        dice2 = random.randint(min, max)
        print(print_in_pink)
        print(int(dice1))
        print(int(dice2))
        print(print_default)
        score = (int(dice1) + int(dice2))
        sum = sum + score
        roll_again = input("Your score for this round is " + str(score) + ". Roll the dices again (y/n)? ")
else:
    print("Ok!")

print(sum)
```

Comment: I'm glad that it helps. Could you give me a upvote? Or accept it as answer?

Answer (score 2):

Just **store the sum in a variable**, and print it later, like this:

```
import colorama
colorama.init()

print_in_green = "\x1b[32m"
print_in_red = "\x1b[31m"
print_in_blue = "\x1b[36m"
print_in_pink = "\x1b[35m"
print_default = "\x1b[0m"

import random
min = 1
max = 6
game_response = input("Would you like to roll your dice (y/n)? ")

# Create variable to store the accumulated score
total_score = 0

if game_response == "y":
    roll_again = "yes"

    while roll_again == "yes" or roll_again == "y":
        print("Rolling the dices...")
        print("The values are:")
        dice1 = random.randint(min, max)
        dice2 = random.randint(min, max)
        print(print_in_pink)
        print(int(dice1))
        print(int(dice2))
        print(print_default)
        score = (int(dice1) + int(dice2))
        roll_again = input("Your score for this round is " + str(score) + ". Roll the dices again (y/n)? ")
        total_score = total_score + score
    print("Here is your score:",total_score)
else:
    print("Ok!")
```

Comment: Your printing of the total score is in the wrong place.  It should be inside the `if`, but outside the `while` loop.  If you have it in the `else`, you will only display it if they do not play the game at all.

Comment: This works perfectly except it isn't printing the final score for some reason. Can you help me fix that? Thank you so much for the help I really appreciate it